# Fade in elements on click and hide more button if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to show 2 more divs, each time the button is clicked. When all divs were shown, the button should disappear. But the button doesn't disappear.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".content").nextAll(':lt(2)').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 3</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 4</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 5</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 6</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 7</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 8</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 9</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 10</div>
    <div class="button">SHOW ME 2 MORE</div>
```

Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9z67k8cd/

Comment: @max checkout the answer I have posted. You just need to do a little change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your js like:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".content:visible:last").nextAll('.content:lt(2)').fadeIn("slow");
  if ($(".content:visible").length === $(".content").length) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 3</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 4</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 5</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 6</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 7</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 8</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 9</div>
    <div class="content hide">Content 10</div>
    <div class="button">SHOW ME 2 MORE</div>
```